# Is there a huge significant difference between the regular canvas and openGL in terms of framerate?

Tags: opengl-es, bitmap, android-canvas, frame-rate

I've been playing around with graphics in android and I noticed that it takes a lot of time and resources to draw a bitmaps with the canvas. Especially in high end games which require many images to be drawn at once, this could be pretty bad for things such as the framerate. If I decide to learn and use openGL, would it make a big difference? Or maybe I'm not using the canvas right?

Comment: How to accept an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of Android you're talking about.

In android version 2.X, all canvas operations are not hardware accelerated, so it's not using the GPU at all, and it processes everything pixel by pixel on the CPU.

In either Android 3 or 4 (I forget which one exactly), hardware acceleration was added to canvas so that you could have a GPU accelerated canvas.

OpenGLES always uses hardware acceleration, so for android 2.X, it will always be much much faster than a canvas (this is your only real option for any kind of game that needs a reasonable framerate).

In hardware accelerated android, you probably won't notice much of a difference between canvas and OpenGL, because they both leverage the GPU, provided that your canvas has hardware acceleration enabled.